# How to make html merge rows table using php array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have the following array that I get from mysql database, after I get all data I should create one table to show all values.

```
Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [groupNo] => 1001
            [name] => james
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupNo] => 1002
            [name] => chen
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [groupNo] => 1002
            [name] => ash
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [groupNo] => 1001
            [name] => mark
        )

)
```

My current table is like this one :

```
Group Number | Name          | Action    |          
-------------+------+---------------------
1001         | James         |           |
------------+----------------+------------
1002         | chen          |           |
-------------+---------------+------------
1002         | ash           |           |
-------------+---------------+------------
1001         | mark          |           |
-------------+---------------+------------
```

But what I want is my table look exactly like below :

```
Group Number | Name          | Action    |          
-------------+------+---------------------
1001         | James         |           |
             +---------------+------------
             | Mark          |           |
-------------+----------------------------
1002         | chen          |           |
             +----------------------------
             | ash           |           |
-------------+----------------------------
```

Below is my code :

```
<?php
if (count($sharingGroup) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sharingGroup); $i++) {
        $sharingGroupRecord = $sharingGroup[$i];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>' . $sharingGroupRecord ['groupNo'] .'</td>
        <td>' . $sharingGroupRecord ['name'] .'</td>
        <td><a name="action" href="#">Action<span>
        </span></a>
</tr>
```

Anybody please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to recreate the array

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($sharingGroup as $item) {
    $newArray[$item['groupNo']][] = $item['name'];
}
```

it'll produce this:

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => james
            [1] => mark
        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [0] => chen
            [1] => ash
        )

)
```

then you loop through the newArray

```
if (count($newArray) > 0) {

    $html = '';

    foreach($newArray as $key => $val) {
       $html .= "<tr>\r\n";    

       $html .= "<td rowspan='".count($val)."'>{$key}</td>\r\n";

       foreach($val as $key => $td) {
           if($key>0) {
              $html.= "<tr>";
           }
           $html .= "<td>{$td}</td>\r\n";
           $html .= "<td>Action</td>\r\n";
           $html .= "</tr>\r\n";
       }        
    }
}
```

and you'll get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8NtBU/) as a result

Here's the [code](http://codepad.org/3WIgI3rx) all in one place

Comment: thanks but it's far from perfect, there are no safeguards in case there's only one child in the new array etc

Comment: @Kostis It's okay.For now this is what I want.Thanks again ! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$transpose=array();
if (count($sharingGroup) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sharingGroup); $i++) {
        $sharingGroupRecord = $sharingGroup[$i];
        $transpose[$sharingGroupRecord['groupNo']][]=$sharingGroupRecord['name'];
    }
print_r($transpose);
$output="<table>";
foreach ($transpose as $groupNo => $group){
    $output.="<tr><td>$groupNo</td><td>";
    foreach ($group as $name){
        $output.="$name<br />";
    }
    $output.="</td></tr>";
}
$output.="</table>";

echo $output;
```

With more rows..

```
<?php
$transpose=array();
if (count($sharingGroup) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sharingGroup); $i++) {
        $sharingGroupRecord = $sharingGroup[$i];
        $transpose[$sharingGroupRecord['groupNo']][]=$sharingGroupRecord['name'];
    }
print_r($transpose);
$transpose_again=array();
foreach ($tranpose as $groupNo=>$group){
    foreach($group => $name){
        $transpose_again[][$groupNo][]=$name;
    }
}
// Now you have a row numbers that is sorted by the groupNo.. I will stop here and let you figure out how to present it and do the rowspan if you really want to..
```

Comment: thanks @MoeTsao it is almost for what I want ,but how to make column for name have one row for each name

Comment: It's doable, but code would get ugly fast. Are you sure you need to have it in separate rows? Use css to present a divider between lines?

Comment: yes ,because I want to add some delete action inside each row name.I don't care how the code would look like,I will customize it later =)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following is your input array

```
$array = array(
    array(
            "groupNo" => 1001,
            "name" => "james"
        ),
    array(
            "groupNo" => 1002,
            "name" => "chen"
        ),
    array(
            "groupNo" => 1002,
            "name" => "ash",
        ),
    array
        (
            "groupNo" => 1001,
            "name" => "mark"
        ),
    array
        (
            "groupNo" => 1003,
            "name" => "marco"
        ),
);
```

Then you could do the following:

```
$newArray =array();
foreach($array as $arr){
    $newArray[$arr['groupNo']][] = $arr["name"];
}
unset($array); // unset the unwanted array.
```

and for printing the table

```
<table border="1">

<?php if(!empty($newArray)){
   foreach($newArray as $key=>$val){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan='".sizeof($val)."'>".$key."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$val[0]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    for($i=1;$i<sizeof($val);$i++){
        echo "<tr><td>".$val[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }

   }

} ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP logic to create a new array with all group members in a single group as a single element of the array

```
<?php
    $group=Array(0=>array('groupNo' => 1001, 'name' => "james"), 1=>array('groupNo' => 1002, 'name' => "chen"), 2=>array('groupNo' => 1002, 'name' => "ash"), 3=>array('groupNo' => 1001, 'name' => "mark"));
    $new_group=array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($group); $i++)
    {
        $new_group[$i]=array($group[$i]['groupNo']);
        for($j=0; $j < count($group); $j++)
        {
            if($new_group[$i][0]==$group[$j]['groupNo'])
            {
                $new_group[$i][]=$group[$j]['name'];
                array_splice($group, $j, 1);
                $j--;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($new_group);
?>
```

### HTML table structure (You need `rowspan` property)

```
<table id=t1 border="2">
    <?php
        if(count($new_group)>0)
            echo "<tr>
                        <th>Group Number
                        <th>Name
                        <th>Action
            </tr>";
        foreach($new_group as $grouping)
        {
            $count=count($grouping)-1;
            echo "<tr>
                    <td rowspan=".$count.">".$grouping[0];
            for($j=1; $j <= $count; $j++)
            {
                echo "<td>".$grouping[$j];
                echo "</tr>";
                if($j<$count)
                    echo "<tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

**[JSfiddle DEMO O/P](http://jsfiddle.net/8NtBU/1/)**